# Why does ls .* show different files than ls ./.*?

Tags: bash, wildcards

Blank file .ignoramus in current directory exists.

```
bojan@localhost:~$ echo $GLOBIGNORE
.ignoramus
bojan@localhost:~$ ls .* | grep ignor
bojan@localhost:~$ ls ./.* | grep ignor
./.ignoramus
```

tools used
    ls (GNU coreutils) 8.23
    GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 4):

The `$GLOBIGNORE` setting is processed by the shell when it expands the wildcard in your command line. In your first case, the shell first expands `.*` to `.ignoramus`, which is matched by `$GLOBIGNORE`, so it is not included in the names passed to `ls`.

In your second case, the shell expands `./.*` to `./.ignoramus`, which is *not* matched by `$GLOBIGNORE`. If you set `$GLOBIGNORE` to `.ignoramus:./.ignoramus` then the behaviour of your second command will match your first.

Answer (score 1):

Short reason: the string `./.ignoramus` is not matching `.ignoramus`.

Short solution: use `GLOBIGNORE=*ignoramus` (also read detail at the end).

```
$ GLOBIGNORE=*ignoramus
$ ls .* | grep ignor                 ### empty
$ ls ./.* | grep ignor               ### also empty
```

The asterisk will match anything (even an slash `/` before the name).
Of course, that will also match `foobar.ignoramus`.
For a couple of workarounds read at the end.

---

Expanded answer:

That also happens with a normal file:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/mytest; cd /tmp/mytest
$ touch f1 f2 filetotest
$ GLOBIGNORE=filetotest
$ ls -1
f1
f2
filetotest

$ ls -1 f*
f1
f2

$ ls -1 *
f1
f2

$ ls -1 ./f*
./f1
./f2
./filetotest
```

GLOBIGNORE will not match `./filetotest`, but if we use:

```
$ GLOBIGNORE="*filetotest"
$ ls -1 ./f*
./f1
./f2

$ ls -1 ./*
./f1
./f2

$ ls -1
f1
f2
filetotest
```

The pattern in GLOBIGNORE will match `(something)filetotest`.

For your example:

```
$ touch .ignoramus
$ GLOBIGNORE='*ignoramus'
ls -1a
.
..
f1
f2
filetotest
.ignoramus

$ ls .* | grep ignor
$ ls ./.* | grep ignor
```

Even with some path in front of file, it works:

```
$ GLOBIGNORE='*ignoramus:*filetotest'
$ mkdir -p long/dir/to/test
$ touch long/dir/to/test/{f3,f4,.ignoramus,.other,filetotest}

$ ls -1 long/dir/to/test/f*
long/dir/to/test/f3
long/dir/to/test/f4

$ ls -1 long/dir/to/test/.[^.]*
long/dir/to/test/.other

$ shopt -s dotglob
$ ls -1 long/dir/to/test/*
long/dir/to/test/f3
long/dir/to/test/f4
long/dir/to/test/.other

$ unset GLOBIGNORE; shopt -s dotglob
$ ls -1 long/dir/to/test/*
long/dir/to/test/f3
long/dir/to/test/f4
long/dir/to/test/filetotest
long/dir/to/test/.ignoramus
long/dir/to/test/.other
```

Of course, that will also match `bar.ignoramus`. If that is not desired, use:

```
$ GLOBIGNORE=.ignoramus:./.ignoramus
```

Or, if you want any path included:

```
$ GLOBIGNORE=.ignoramus:*/.ignoramus
```